# Can't add session variable - ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

I am not very confident with Rails but have recently started adding custom session variables in order to store some data such as id's. I am trying to set a call id to a recently created value but keep getting an error.

Code:

```
callid = Call.createCall(sessionid,tp_cd)
session[:callid] = callid
```

This exact same thing works in other actions in the same controller, but here I get:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `callid`)
```

I am simply calling this action with a POST call in order to manipulate some data and set this session variable to be used later. There must be something fundamental that I am missing about how session variables work. Is there anything obvious that could cause this error?

Comment: Try doing `request.session[:callid] = callid` to see if anything else is interfering with your session.

Comment: Hey Iceman, by using request.session[:callid] I managed to make it work, not sure how that's different from the normal one, but everything seems to work now.

Comment: It's different because if you only use `session`, Rails looks for a model called `Session`, not the `Session` that is part of the request cycle. I hope I'm not confusing you too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives an error because Rails looks for a model called `Session`, not the session object that is part of the request cycle.

You can get the session like this

```
request.session[:callid] = callid
```

Answer (score -1):

In rails, creating a new record on the model name is just create method.

```
callid = Call.createCall(sessionid,tp_cd)
```

so it should be like this:

```
callid= call.create(params)
```

in params you need to define it like this: column name : your variable/value. So what columns are in your Call model? if you have session_id column, it will be like this:

```
callid= call.create(session_id: value_given )
```